# Usar classe do projeto Droid no PCL Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-forms

Como faço para usar uma classe que foi criada no projeto `Droid` no `PCL` ?

Eu criei uma classe nova que irá salvar a imagem em uma pasta no projeto, 
porém preciso chamar esta classe no `PCL`.

Minha classe:

```
namespace PCI.APP.Droid
{
    public class SalvarFoto
    {
        public bool SalvarFotoPasta(string Imagem, string ImgNome)
        {
            try
            {
                String caminho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageUsers"];

                if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(caminho))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(caminho);
                }

                string imagemNome = ImgNome + ".png";

                string imgPasta = Path.Combine(caminho, imagemNome);

                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Imagem);

                File.WriteAllBytes(imgPasta, imageBytes);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A abordagem mais correta para esta operação é utilizar Injeção de Dependência. O PCL não deve ter referencia aos projetos específicos de cada plataforma, para darmos uma visibilidade do mesmo para o PCL utilizamos a IjD. Como fazer?

1 - Crie uma interface chamada ISalvarFoto no seu PCL e implemente ela no seu projeto droid.

```
public interface ISalvarFoto 
{
     public bool SalvarFotoPasta(string Imagem, string ImgNome);
}
```

2 - Em seguinde, adicione a anotacão ao seu assembly

```
[assembly: Dependecy(typeof(PCI.APP.Droid.SalvarFoto))]
namespace PCI.APP.Droid
{
   public class SalvarFoto : ISalvarFoto
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

3 - Agora é só requisitar a implementação da classe. No trecho de código onde você precisa da implementação da classe basta fazer:

```
var salvarFoto = DependencyService.Get<ISalvarFoto>();
```

Nos requisitamos uma classe que implemente a interface e como marcamos a devida classe o DependencyService é capaz de resolver e criar a instancia necessária.